Question about ignorant vs deliberate sins?
Luke 23:34, Jesus said, “Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they are doing.”
Heb 10:26 - “for if they go on winning willfully, no more sacrifice remains for sin…”
Thank you all for accepting my question.  I have been studying the subject of ignorant vs willful sin for a while, and a lot of the answers I read to the question of  “does God forgive willful sins” seems to be illusive.  The words don’t seem to mean the same in English as they do in Hebrew.  In English “ignorant” seems to mean “I didn’t know, or I did and just overlooked it”, and “deliberate” just means it was “on purpose”.  I don’t believe this is the same sense the Biblical authors had in mind.
Looking at the first sins in the Bible has helped draw a clearer picture for me.  Adam and Eve’s sin fell into the category of the Biblical definition of “ignorance” I believe because they were forgiven.  Eve was deceived and sinned (she knew it was wrong but convinced herself it was ok), but Adam was not deceived and still chose to sin.  The very first sacrifice still covered him.
Next is Cain.  His sin was premeditated, against dire warning, and he had hatred in his heart against Abel and God which was evident in his response, and which later the Torah uses to define capital murder which had no forgiveness.  Is this the more accurate picture of deliberate sin? And is ignorant sin better defined as sin where there may be knowledge, weakness, and even deception, but where there is the absence of rebellious premeditation and some level of hatred for God’s law?
The reason I ask is that the ultimate issue is access to forgiveness for sinners.  Jesus said “forgive them, for they don’t know what they’re doing”, Paul said he was forgiven because he sinned “ignorantly in unbelief”, and of course there are all of the scary passages in the book of Hebrews.
Thank you for your answers in advance.  If I can do anything better please let me know.
